# How to make layout height equal to its width in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I want to make all of my `CardView`'s height equal to their width and also I want each `CardView` to occupy the same part of user's device screen. How can I do that? My code is like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/tool1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tool2">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/too_4_background"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/emoji_background"
                            android:gravity="center">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="&#x1F633;"
                                android:textSize="15dp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="ارسال رایگان"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/tool2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tool1"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tool3">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/too_4_background"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/emoji_background"
                            android:gravity="center">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="&#x1F633;"
                                android:textSize="15dp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="ارسال رایگان"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/tool3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tool2"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tool4">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/too_4_background"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/emoji_background"
                            android:gravity="center">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="&#x1F633;"
                                android:textSize="15dp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="ارسال رایگان"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/tool4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tool3"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/too_4_background"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/emoji_background"
                            android:gravity="center">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="&#x1F633;"
                                android:textSize="15dp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="ارسال رایگان"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You want to make square cardview?

Comment: You should calculate device screen width and after subtracting padding and margin (if any) calculate the width of card. Now you have width just set the height using **LayoutParams**

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån Yes

Comment: @HarishKamboj I know that but I want to do this through xml

Comment: it is not possible to do through XML AFAIK

Comment: Did anyone of you hear about ConstraintLayout, read some doc...

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko You can do it through XML bro, You just need some constraints.. and it's very easy

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån oh, looks like that is one of the features of constraintLayout. Probably time to learn it for me

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Yeah, You must get your hands good on ConstraintLayout pretty soon as this will help to slow down your development time IMO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the question is to set the same height and width, here is the code.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

</android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a custom CardView, say SquareCardView:

```
public class SquareCardView extends CardView {
  public SquareCardView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public SquareCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public SquareCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = Math.min(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
  }
}
```

And then, use that custom card view into your Layout:

```
<com.yourPackageName.SquareCardView
    android:id="@+id/tool1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tool2">
```

Comment: With ConstraintLayout we can set the height and width to "0dp" and add app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" to achieve the same result.

Comment: thanks. this is a way to do that but not the best way.